# Manage Windows Server 2008 R2 Terminal From Windows 8

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-8

I am managing a small network at work that consists of a server running Windows Server 2008 R2 and about six PCs with Windows XP.

We are starting the process of transitioning to Windows 8. The first desktop purchased is mine ("the IT computer"), and it has Windows 8 "basic" version.

Because it is the basic version, I am not able to connect to a domain. Ideally, those in charge will agree to upgrade it to the Pro version.

Until then, I need to be able to use Remote Desktop to access the server and other computers, which are all on the same domain.

Is this possible with out connecting the Windows 8 computer to the same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Remote Desktop client from any version of Windows 8 to get into anything.

Once you are on a proper version of Windows and on the domain, you'll want to install the [Windows 8 RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39296) tools.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to verify; the RSAT tools are only needed for the Pro version or for 8.1? I may misunderstand, but how would the Windows 8 machine detect the IP address of the Windows Server 2008 if it is not on the domain? The Windows 8 computer is connected to the wireless router on the network for internet access, but that is the only connection it has. Thanks

Comment: @CherokeeLakes correct only for "Pro" which is why I mentioned "Once you are on a proper version of Windows" (the basic edition is pretty shit for doing this kind of work on).

Comment: Okay, great. And the WIndows 8 machine will be able to remote into the 2008 Server through the servers IP address without being on the domain?

Comment: Absolutally, yes